# Don't know how to link within a page in HTML

Tags: html, anchor

How can I link to specific part of a page in html 5? I'm using the `<a href="#">` for the target but it only takes me to the home page. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an extremely rudimentary aspect of HTML addressed in any beginner tutorial.

Comment: Please learn correct markup in SO. HTML markup such as `<a>` will disappear unless you enclose it in the backticks, rendering your question incomprehensible. You could easily have checked for this problem by doing a quick sanity check of how your question looked after you posted it.

Comment: (In answer to your edit/comment posted as an answer:) No, your post did include the HTML with the tag, but you failed to follow basic formatting guidelines for code. No, the suggestion is not to use a `div`, it's to mark a point in your document so you have somewhere to jump to. No, it has nothing to do with `base`. No, a jump to an anchor within a document will work just fine locally. No, this has nothing to do with HTML5, it was all there in HTML1.

Comment: Then why doesn't it work? I have 3 websites where I've used these in hundreds of cases. I'm sure a better answer is on its way.

Comment: Why doesn't *what* work? You've used *what* in hundreds of cases? Using `href='#'` to try to link to some undefined location within  a page? Do you think HTML is going to read your mind to figure out where to link to? Does it not make sense that to "link within a page" you would have to somehow designate where within the page you wanted to link to, and then somehow specify that was the place you wanted to link to?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `href` attribute of `a` element. The url in the href must begin with `#` sign followed by `id` of an element on the page.

```
<div id="one">asdf</div>
<a href="#one">Link to asdf div (a part of the page)</a>
```